# How do I enable Frames by default in IronPython 2.7.5?

Tags: ironpython

How can I set -X:Frames or -X:FullFrames by default for IronPython?  I cannot type it in every time to make certain scripts work.

I cannot find any settings in the IronPython configuration files.

This is the source I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Hosting/PythonOptionsParser.cs), though I'm not sure the relevance here.

```
case "-X:Frames":
                LanguageSetup.Options["Frames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;
                break;
            case "-X:FullFrames":
                LanguageSetup.Options["Frames"] = LanguageSetup.Options["FullFrames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;
                break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do that right now.  One possible option would be a IRONPYTHONOPTS environment variable, but that would have to wait for 2.7.6. IronPython 3 will make -X:FullFrames the default and provide -X:NoFrames instead.

Comment: I don't see how anyone's using it for the web, but thanks for the information.  I sure wish I could.